# Tkinter Image Resizing (smaller)

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to resize my GIF image in TKinter using the PhotoImage() function with the subsample call. I know this takes every third pixel of the image, but it's the only way I have seen for how to shrink an image (since zoom() only takes integers). Is there a better way I can shrink an image? The way it shows up on Tkinter is much worse than if I zoom out in Paint. I want it to be about half of the image shown. The original quality isn't great I guess, but it seems like it should improve if it's smaller and not get worse?

Original: 
[image]

Tkinter:
[image]

```
curr_weather = PhotoImage(file="sunny.gif")
    curr_weather = curr_weather.subsample(3, 3)
    label = Label(root, image=curr_weather, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0)
    # label.image = curr_weather
    label.grid(row = weather_start_row+1, column = 0)
```

Comment: How do you feel about using a third-party image manipulation library, such as Pillow?

Comment: I'm open to whatever works - I don't know enough to have an educated opinion ha

Comment: In that case, [Image.resize] might be useful to you. You can resize to whatever dimensions you want, and you have several options for which resampling filter to use.

Comment: Ok let me try that - just briefly reading about it now - it looks like I can pass PNG files, which might look better anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Whoops, I flubbed posting the link there. Sounds like you found the documentation anyway, but for future reference I meant to link to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Comment: Yep - perfect. Now I'm down the rabbit hole trying to install it from command line hah. Thanks!